# Unable to install lmtest package

Tags: r, macos-sierra

I'm unable to download packages in R when using a Mac. I've tried the simple suggested solutions. Please help.

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lmtest’
* removing ‘/Users/Saundy/Library/R/3.4/library/lmtest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lmtest’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in

```
‘/private/var/folders/b7/6zytq47j2k5d3knkv0zjtzbm0000gn/T/RtmpMY0uuf/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: What command have you tried?

Comment: So i just go to Tools > Install Packages > lmtest..

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages('lmtest', dependencies = TRUE)`?

Comment: I have tried that. I end up getting the following,

**gfortran -arch x86_64   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c altmov.f -o altmov.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory**

Comment: Can you post the output of ```sessionInfo()```so we can help you troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0):

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.14